# Spring consul turbine error - Could not initiate connection to host, giving up: []

Tags: java, spring-cloud, consul, hystrix, turbine

I want to read services registered at consul from my turbine application. I have configured turbine for that as :

Bootstrap.yml

```
 server:
 port: 8050

spring:
 cloud:
  consul:
   discovery:
  prefer-ip-address: true
 host: *****hostName where consul reside****
 port: 8500

turbine:
 aggregator:
   clusterConfig: dm-geo
 appConfig: dm-geo
```

Have dependencies -

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
 </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-turbine</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

on main application class -

```
  @EnableTurbine
  @EnableHystrixDashboard
  @EnableDiscoveryClient
```

These all configuration are done on turbine application.

Now each service which is registered on consul , has dependencies -

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

and
          `@EnableHystrix`
          `@EnableDiscoveryClient`
on application class with `HystrixCommand` at our rest calling method to other services with proper fallback logic.

application.properties:-

```
  spring.application.name=dm-geo
```

Now our python script with required configuration discover these service and register on consul.
When I try to get each hystrix.stream , I am able to get hystrix dashboard for that.

but from my turbine application , error is logged as

```
"timestamp":"2016-07-27T17:33:14.406+05:30","message":"Could not initiate connection to host, giving up,"logger_name":"com netflix turbine monitor instance InstanceMonitor","thread_name":"InstanceMonitor"
```

can somebody help in this regard???

Comment: spring.application.name needs to go in bootstrap.properties, have you tried that?

Comment: Yes today I worked on this . and it is resolved now. as for our application turbine.stream was a authenticated URL so I have to skip this which then worked perfectly to show the turbine stream and dashboard. as        security.ignored = URL path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is resolved now as for our application turbine. Basically the stream was authenticated via URL so I have to skip this which then worked perfectly to show the turbine stream and dashboard. For example:

```
security.ignored = /turbine.stream
```

in spring boot application.